# Is there any operation to multiply each element in the first array to each element in the second array in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Is there any function (like `fold`, `map`, `filter`), which gets 2 arrays and lambda-function (for example multiplication) as parameters and returns third array?

I've used cycle for, but is there more beautiful method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is [`zip`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip.html) (nice example at the bottom of the page), see this (different) example:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val a = arrayOf( 1, 2, 3, 4 )
    val b = arrayOf( 1, 2, 3, 4 )
    
    val c = a.zip(b) { i, j -> i * j }
    
    println(c)
}
```

which outputs

```
[1, 4, 9, 16]
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a built in specifically but you can do this:
`array1.zip(array2).map { (x,y) -> x*y }`